# how does the createDocumentFragment() method works?

Tags: html, dom

I am learning the HTML DOM model and i am stuck at a problem.I am unable to understand how does the createDocumentFragment() method works in the following code.

HTML CODE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<ul><li>Coffee</li><li>Tea</li></ul>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>

function myFunction()
{
var d=document.createDocumentFragment();
d.appendChild(document.getElementsByTagName("LI")[0]);
d.childNodes[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue="Milk";
document.getElementsByTagName("UL")[0].appendChild(d);
};

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I understand that createDocumentFragment() method creates a imaginary Node object which  is usefull when you want to extract parts of your document.And the appendChild() method appends the node  to the last child of a node.But what does the following mean:

```
 d.childNodes[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue="Milk";
```

Shouldn't  it be `d.childNodes[0].nodeValue="Milk";`?. Please can someone give me a clear explanation of how the above DOM model is working!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a text node inside the `<li>` representing the string "Coffee", and that's what gets replaced with "Milk". The first child of the fragment is the `<li>`, whose first child is the text node.